# SQL, with if then else, move some value from a column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

in SQL Server,

how can I move value from a column to another with conditional (if then else) ?
I'm explain with an example.

I have a table with

| Article | Desc. | UM | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | Flower | PC | 5001 |
| Item2 | Paper | PC | 6001 |
| Item2 | Paper | CT | 6002 |
| Item3 | Pen | CT | 7001 |
| Item4 | Eraser | PC | 8001 |

I need to have

| Article | Desc. | Value PC | ValueCT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | Flower | 5001 | NULL |
| Item2 | Paper | 6001 | NULL |
| Item2 | Paper | NULL | 6002 |
| Item3 | Pen | NULL | 7001 |
| Item4 | Eraser | 8001 | NULL |

I thought to do a If then else

Something like that:
`if UM = 'PC' then begin instruction to move value to "Value PC" end else begin instruction to move value to "Value CT" end`

But I don't know which instruction use to move only value that I need to move.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Look at `PIVOT` or conditional aggregation if you expect a single row, if a person can have both values and you expect 1 row. If not, just use a `CASE` expression or the `IIF` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you just need a simple case expression,

```
select Article, [Desc.],
    case when UM = 'PC' then Value end ValuePC,
    case when UM = 'CT' then Value end ValueCT
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you! It was more simple than my idea!